# Number of physical pages in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand how pages are created in SQL server.
I've made very simple example:

```
-- 0 pages
CREATE TABLE TMP_1(
    id int)

-- 2 pages  
INSERT INTO TMP_1
VALUES(1)   

-- 3 pages
SELECT  *
INTO TMP_2
FROM TMP_1
```

At first table TMP_1 has no pages, which is rather intuitive because there is no data. After 1 row is inserted there are two pages. One of course stores data but what is the second one?

Table TMP_2 should be identical to TMP_1 but it has 3 pages, why?

I'm checking number of pages with following code:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) AS TotalPages, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) AS UsedPages, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) AS UnusedPages
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
    AND t.name LIKE 'TMP%'
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Comment: But I could not replicate.. I got same result for both `TMP_1` and `TMP_2`

Comment: Is it possible that it depends on settings in SQL SERVER?

Comment: This is version os SQL SERVER that I'm using: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4297.0 (X64)   Nov 22 2013 17:24:14   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )

Comment: Am not sure about that.. Lets wait for DBA gurus +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At first table TMP_1 has no pages, which is rather intuitive because there is no data

Sql server will allocate pages only upon the first insert

> After 1 row is inserted there are two pages. One of course stores data but what is the second one?

This is called IAM Page..

SQL Server uses index allocation maps to track which pages have been allocated to which allocation unit. They are stored in special IAM pages.

Each IAM page covers an area of 64000 extents in a file, a so-called GAM-interval. If multiple IAM pages are needed for a single allocation unit, the form a double linked list, the IAM chain.

See Demo below..

```
create table t1
(
id int
)

drop table t1
insert into t1
values(1)

DBCC TRACEON (3604);

DBCC IND('PerformanceV3','t1',-1)
```

Output stripped:

```
iam_chain_type  PartitionID   PageType
In-row data 72057594048217088   10
In-row data 72057594048217088   1
```

for the third question:

> Table TMP_2 should be identical to TMP_1 but it has 3 pages, why ?

this is a data page ,my best guess would be assuming ,this is the way
select Into works internally ,when you insert,SQL can always create page dynamically when needed,but with select into,it created one more data page additionally..

As to why ,select into is showing all three pages as used :
I believe allocation DMV will capture all page **allocations**,but we are talking about used here..which can be seen  by below DBCC commands more precisely..

```
dbcc traceon(3604)
dbcc ind('performancev3','t2',-1)

dbcc page(0,1,36639,3)
```

References:
http://sqlity.net/en/2315/index-allocation-map/
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-using-dbcc-page-and-dbcc-ind-to-find-out-if-page-splits-ever-roll-back/

Comment: Thanks! It answers the first of my two questions.

Comment: @TomekTarczynski:added my guess ,but would leave open for new answers

Comment: If I understand correctly then this page should be empty (unused), but according to SQL server all 3 pages are used.

Comment: For select into case,you have three pages,two data pages(one used and one unused) and one IAM page (used).hope this is clear

Comment: I get that, but the query that retrieves number of pages says that in TMP_2 there are 3 pages and all of them are used.